# google sheets script editor - send email if there is specific text in column E

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- if any row in column E has "get fish" then the email should send, - is this part
  correct? : -

  *if (monthSales = "get fish"){*

the full code is below: -

```
function CheckSales() {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("myfish").getRange("E1:E1000"); 
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValues();
  // Check totals sales
  if (monthSales = "get fish"){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Get Fish ' 
    var subject = 'Get Fish';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue(); getValues()` returns a 2d Array even for one cell. `getValue()` returns one value. Look at what [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns.

Comment: hi i don't know what that means because i'm a noob ,  i think that you're saying to change the var email address part by adding getValues() after the ; 

like this: - 

var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue(); getValues()

Comment: would like add here that currently i'm getting an email to get fish even when all the rows in column E are blank

Comment: I'm saying use `getValue()` instead of  `getValues();`  i.e. take the  s off.

Comment: from reading the getvalues link that you posted, my guess is that the script is currently an empty string so getValues is sending an email when the cells are empty .. is that correct?

Comment: It's not a string at all. It's an array.  if you want to leave that way then change the sendEmail line to this `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress[0][0], subject, message);`

Comment: oh right ok - got it - would this work if one single cell in column E says get fish?

Comment: Yes. If you just want to  get one cell then generally you would use getValue() if you want to get a bunch of cells that  are all adjacent then you would use getValues() which is much more efficient because it only takes one access rather than using getValue() a bunch of times.  You can read about this in the best practices section  on the support page of the documentation.

Comment: is this part correct to look for the text "get fish" in Range("E1:E1000") : -

 if (monthSales = "get fish"){

Comment: No it should be `var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValues();` and that would return a two dimensional array that looks like `[[value],[value],[value],[value].....]`

Comment: You should use the debugger because it will help you to see what's being returned

Comment: okay i've changed var monthSales to getvalues and var emailAddress to getvalue

Comment: is this now the correct code to send an email if any row in column E says the specific text "get fish" ? it should not send an email if the the column is empty

Comment: i've updated the code in the question 
but today time-based trigger ran (between 1 and 2 am) and i received the 'Get Fish' email even though column E does not say 'get fish' in any of the rows